# how to implement AuthenticationEntryPoint and AuthenticationProvider together in spring security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

Hi Spring Security experts.

**My Requirements.**

I have two set of UIs. One set is Login and Logout which needs to be protected by spring security using basic Authentication (using username password credential). I used  `HybridAuthenticationProvider` implementing `AuthenticationProvider` and achieved it.

The second and rest of UIs need to be supported by passing token in HTTP Header. I used `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` implementing `AuthenticationEntryPoint` + `GenericFilterBean` and could achieve it.

Now I want to make single spring-security.xml to achieve above both functionality. Ultimately I have combine set of UI pages where Login/Logout pages I want to protect by credential (`AuthenticationProvider`) and rest of UIs I want to protect with token (`AuthenticationEntryPoint`).

When I put all together in spring-security.xml (mentioned below), I get following exception.

**Exception :**

> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':
> Cannot resolve reference to bean
> 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while
> setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Could
> not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name
> arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

Sample Spring-security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="hybridAuthenticationProvider">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:http realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true"
    auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>


<bean id="CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="com.ckatudia.tutorial.authentrypoint.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
   class="com.ckatudia.tutorial.authentrypoint.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" />

<bean id="TokenUtils"
    class="com.ckatudia.tutorial.authentrypoint.TokenUtils" />

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="com.ckatudia.tutorial.auth.TokenAuthenticationProvider" />

<bean id="hybridAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.ckatudia.tutorial.auth.HybridAuthenticationProvider">
</bean>  
    
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="hybridAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I removed authentication-manager-ref="hybridAuthenticationProvider" then I was getting following exception while deployment.

**Exception :**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in
> the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the
> ordering in your security:http namespace or FilterChainProxy bean
> configuration

Answer (score 1):

You have this exception because de "pattern" attribute of the http element defaults to "/**".  Since you have two "http" element without specific patterns , the default value is taken and they each covers the same set of uis.

Try to add different patterns on the two :

```
<http pattern="/foo/**" ... >
  ...
</http>

<http pattern="/bar/**" ... >
  ...
</http>
```